# Reset svg pattern origin point

Tags: svg

I'm trying to add a triangle pattern to each end of a svg `rect`. Where the `rect` can be varying widths. The problem is that depending on where the `rect` starts and ends, the pattern can start in the middle of the triangle. I need it to always start at the beginning.
I've tried setting the `patternUnits`, messing with the `viewBox` for both the main svg and the pattern.

This example shows that the 2nd and 3rd stripe have wrongly aligned patterns

```html
<svg width="346" height="100">
    <defs>
        <pattern x="0" y="0" id="zigZag" width="2" height="6" viewBox="0 0 2 6" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
            <polygon points="0 0 2 3 0 6" style="fill: rgb(0, 0, 0);"></polygon>
        </pattern>
        <pattern x="0" y="0" id="zagZig" width="2" height="6" viewBox="0 0 2 6" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" patternTransform="rotate(180)">
            <polygon points="0 0 2 3 0 6" style="fill: rgb(0, 0, 0);"></polygon>
        </pattern>
    </defs>
    <rect width="346" height="100" rx="10" style="fill: rgba(255, 101, 35, 0.75);"></rect>
    <rect x="14" width="16" height="100" style="fill: rgb(255, 101, 35);"></rect>
    <rect x="12" width="2" height="100" fill="url(#zagZig)"></rect>
    <rect x="30" width="2" height="100" fill="url(#zigZag)"></rect>
    <rect x="51" width="50" height="100" style="fill: rgb(255, 101, 35);"></rect>
    <rect x="49" width="2" height="100" fill="url(#zagZig)"></rect>
    <rect x="101" width="2" height="100" fill="url(#zigZag)"></rect>
    <rect x="121" width="80" height="100" style="fill: rgb(255, 101, 35);"></rect>
    <rect x="119" width="2" height="100" fill="url(#zagZig)"></rect>
    <rect x="201" width="2" height="100" fill="url(#zigZag)"></rect>
</svg>
```

This example shows that changing the the x position to an even number aligns the pattern correctly.

```html
    <svg width="346" height="100">
        <defs>
            <pattern x="0" y="0" id="zigZag" width="2" height="6" viewBox="0 0 2 6" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
                <polygon points="0 0 2 3 0 6" style="fill: rgb(0, 0, 0);"></polygon>
            </pattern>
            <pattern x="0" y="0" id="zagZig" width="2" height="6" viewBox="0 0 2 6" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" patternTransform="rotate(180)">
                <polygon points="0 0 2 3 0 6" style="fill: rgb(0, 0, 0);"></polygon>
            </pattern>
        </defs>
        <rect width="346" height="100" rx="10" style="fill: rgba(255, 101, 35, 0.75);"></rect> 
        <rect x="14" width="16" height="100" style="fill: rgb(255, 101, 35);"></rect>
        <rect x="12" width="2" height="100" fill="url(#zagZig)"></rect>
        <rect x="30" width="2" height="100" fill="url(#zigZag)"></rect>
        <rect x="50" width="50" height="100" style="fill: rgb(255, 101, 35);"></rect>
        <rect x="48" width="2" height="100" fill="url(#zagZig)"></rect>
        <rect x="100" width="2" height="100" fill="url(#zigZag)"></rect>
        <rect x="120" width="80" height="100" style="fill: rgb(255, 101, 35);"></rect>
        <rect x="118" width="2" height="100" fill="url(#zagZig)"></rect>
        <rect x="200" width="2" height="100" fill="url(#zigZag)"></rect>
    </svg>
```

How can I get this alignment without having to changes the x position which is driven by data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there is an easy way to make patterns work how you want here.  Not automatically anyway.

One solution would be to create alternate versions of your patterns for the odd coordinate case. See `zigZagOdd` and `zagZigOdd` in the following example.

```html
<svg width="100%" viewBox="0 0 346 100">
    <defs>
        <pattern x="0" y="0" id="zigZag" width="2" height="6" viewBox="0 0 2 6" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
            <polygon points="0 0 2 3 0 6" style="fill: rgb(0, 0, 0);"></polygon>
        </pattern>
        <pattern x="1" y="0" id="zigZagOdd" width="2" height="6" viewBox="0 0 2 6" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
            <polygon points="0 0 2 3 0 6" style="fill: rgb(0, 0, 0);"></polygon>
        </pattern>
        <pattern x="0" y="0" id="zagZig" width="2" height="6" viewBox="0 0 2 6" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" patternTransform="rotate(180)">
            <polygon points="0 0 2 3 0 6" style="fill: rgb(0, 0, 0);"></polygon>
        </pattern>
        <pattern x="1" y="0" id="zagZigOdd" width="2" height="6" viewBox="0 0 2 6" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" patternTransform="rotate(180)">
            <polygon points="0 0 2 3 0 6" style="fill: rgb(0, 0, 0);"></polygon>
        </pattern>
    </defs>
    <rect width="346" height="100" rx="10" style="fill: rgba(255, 101, 35, 0.75);"></rect>
    <rect x="14" width="16" height="100" style="fill: rgb(255, 101, 35);"></rect>
    <rect x="12" width="2" height="100" fill="url(#zagZig)"></rect>
    <rect x="30" width="2" height="100" fill="url(#zigZag)"></rect>
    <rect x="51" width="50" height="100" style="fill: rgb(255, 101, 35);"></rect>
    <rect x="49" width="2" height="100" fill="url(#zagZigOdd)"></rect>
    <rect x="101" width="2" height="100" fill="url(#zigZagOdd)"></rect>
    <rect x="121" width="80" height="100" style="fill: rgb(255, 101, 35);"></rect>
    <rect x="119" width="2" height="100" fill="url(#zagZigOdd)"></rect>
    <rect x="201" width="2" height="100" fill="url(#zigZagOdd)"></rect>
</svg>
```

However, if your goal was simply to reduce SVG file size and make it easy to apply your patterned fringes, then you could use a different method instead.  I'd recommend the `<use>` element.

```html
<svg width="100%" viewBox="0 0 346 100">
    <defs>
        <pattern x="0" y="0" id="fringe" width="2" height="6" viewBox="0 0 2 6" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
            <polygon points="0 0 2 3 0 6" style="fill: rgb(0, 0, 0);"></polygon>
        </pattern>
        <rect id="zigZag" width="2" height="100" fill="url(#fringe)"/>
        <rect id="zagZig" width="2" height="100" fill="url(#fringe)" transform="scale(-1,1)"/>
    </defs>
    <rect width="346" height="100" rx="10" style="fill: rgba(255, 101, 35, 0.75);"></rect>
    <rect x="14" width="16" height="100" style="fill: rgb(255, 101, 35);"></rect>
    <use x="14" xlink:href="#zagZig"/>
    <use x="30" xlink:href="#zigZag"/>
    <rect x="51" width="50" height="100" style="fill: rgb(255, 101, 35);"></rect>
    <use x="51" xlink:href="#zagZig"/>
    <use x="101" xlink:href="#zigZag"/>
    <rect x="121" width="80" height="100" style="fill: rgb(255, 101, 35);"></rect>
    <use x="121" xlink:href="#zagZig"/>
    <use x="201" xlink:href="#zigZag"/>
</svg>
```